# Do these equations create a helix wrapped into a torus?

Tags: geometry, functions, locus

I don't have any graphing software capable of plotting this, but it makes sense to me.

First a circle:

$$
x = r\cos\theta \\
y = r\sin\theta
$$

Then a sine wave wrapped into a circle:

$$
x = (r+\cos\theta)\cos\theta\\
y = (r+\sin\theta)\sin\theta
$$

And finally, add in the z-coordinate:

$$
z = \sin\theta
$$

Is this correct? If not, what's wrong with it?

$$
x = (r+\cos\theta)\cos\theta = r\cos\theta + \cos^2\theta\\
y = (r+\sin\theta)\sin\theta = r\sin\theta + \sin^2\theta\\
z = \sin\theta
$$

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192067/parameterization-of-helical-torus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need two radii to decribe a torus. Let's call them $a$ and $b$. Then the parametric equations of the torus are:
$$x = (a + b\cos u)\cos v$$
$$y = (a + b\cos u)\sin v$$
$$z = b\sin u$$

Then, to get a helical curve, set $v = ku$, where $k << 1$.

Here's the result with $a=3$, $b=1$, $k=0.05$:
[image]

Comment: Okay, but for a helix of radius 1, doesn't that just simplify to my equations?

Comment: A torus has **two** radii. If you set them both equal to the same value, you get a sphere.

Comment: I think you mean a circle, but yes, I'm aware of that. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: I see. With my notation, you are setting $a=r$ and $b=1$. So, we agree. But, also, you are setting $k=1$, so your curve will not be very helix-like -- it will only wind around the torus once.

Comment: No, I meant sphere.

Comment: I just needed a basic idea first, so I can mess around with the properties. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The surface is a sphere; the curve is a circle.

Comment: You don't get a sphere when $a=b$, you get a [horn torus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torus#Geometry). You get a sphere of radius $b$ when you require that $a=0$.

Comment: I don't quite understand, could you perhaps make another image to illustrate what you're saying?

Comment: [Here's the picture from Wikipedia](http://i.stack.imgur.com/inP40.png).

Comment: @zev -- you're right. Sorry.

Comment: @ZevChonoles That's when the inner radius is zero and the outer radius is positive, but if the radii are equal it should be a circle.

Comment: There is a central circle to the torus of radius $a$. The torus is the surface of distance $b$ from the central circle. When you set $a=0$ and let $b>0$, you get the surface of distance $b$ from a *point* (the central circle has radius 0), which is a sphere of radius $b$. When you set $b=0$ and let $a>0$, you get a circle of radius $a$.

Comment: @user912: By the way, using `HelixPlot[4,1,1]`, [here is a plot of what your equations produce](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fcCxG.png). Only using one wind makes it hardly recognizable as a helix :)

Comment: @ZevChonoles I know it's only one, but it can easily be expanded to include variables for number of turns, as was shown in one of the answers.

Answer (score 8):

Here's the parametrization for a helix of $n$ winds wrapped around a torus of major radius $R$ and minor radius $r$:
$$\begin{align*}
x&=(R+r\cos(nt))\cos(t)\\
y&=(R+r\cos(nt))\sin(t)\\
z&=r\sin(nt)
\end{align*}$$

Making this into a function in *Mathematica*,

```
HelixPlot[R_, r_, n_] := 
 Show[ParametricPlot3D[{(R + r Cos[t]) Cos[u], (R + r Cos[t]) Sin[u], 
    r Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 30, 
   Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3]], 
  ParametricPlot3D[{(R + r Cos[n*t]) Cos[t], (R + r Cos[n*t]) Sin[t], 
    r Sin[n*t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotPoints -> 30, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}]]
```

we can toy with different settings.

`HelixPlot[6, 2, 5]` produces

[image]

`HelixPlot[6, 1, 10]` produces

[image]

`HelixPlot[6, 5, 20]` produces

[image]

Comment: So basically, my equations are correct?

Comment: Basically yes, but your equations don't allow one to vary the minor radius of the torus or the number of winds.

Comment: I was just wanting to make sure that the basic shape was right, before modelling simulations on it. :P