# Parametric form of a double helix around torus

Tags: general-topology, geometry, curves

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crx0l.png)

[Reference_1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461547/whats-the-equation-of-helix-surface/461637#461637)

[Reference_2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470538/helix-in-a-helix)

[Reference_3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324527/do-these-equations-create-a-helix-wrapped-into-a-torus)

I am working on a model to determine the a double helix around a torus. I am aware of the equation for a standard helix in parametric form. I would appreciate if anyone could help me on this. Thanks
My code does not work for double helix on toroid: I want to control the radius of the smaller helix and the number of turns. I would appreciate any suggestions.

**HELIX ON HELIX_CYLINDRICAL**

```
%HELIX ON HELIX_CYLINDRICAL
clear
clc
%
syms t r R h
assume(t,'real')
assume(R,'real')
assume(h,'real')
% CYLINDRICAL HELIX
x=h*t;
y=R*cos(t);
z=R*sin(t);

% % HELIX ON TORUS
% %       VARIABLES
% R=3;% MAJOR RADIUS
% r=1;% MINOR RADIUS
% n=6;% No. of loops
% x = (R + r*cos(n*t)).*cos(t);
% y = r*sin(n*t);
% z = (R + r*cos(n*t)).*sin(t);

% r_vec is the equation of the curve of interest: here helix
r_vec=[x;y;z];
dx=diff(x);
dy=diff(y);
dz=diff(z);
tan_vec=[dx;dy;dz];
nor_vec=diff(tan_vec)/simplify(norm(diff(tan_vec)));
binor_vec=simplify((cross( tan_vec, nor_vec))/norm(tan_vec));
%parametrized for the next curve
syms a
assume(a,'real')
%Number of turns of the second helix
n2=12;
u=n2*t;
S= r_vec + a.*nor_vec.*cos(u)+a.*binor_vec.*sin(u);
% VARIABLES FOR THE SECOND LEVEL HELIX
% a= radius 
h_num=1; R_num=3; a_num=0.5;
S1=subs(S, [h, R, a], [h_num, R_num, a_num]);
% %%Plotting
% R=6; r=2; n=5;
t1 = 0:pi/100:40*pi;
% u1 = 0:pi/15:2*pi;
% x1=R.*cos(t)+r.*cos(t).*cos(n.*t);
% y1=R*sin(t)+r*cos(n.*t).*sin(t);
% z1=r*sin(n.*t);
% x1=S1(1)
% y1=S1(2)
% z1=S1(3)
x2=double(subs(S1(1),t ,t1)); y2=double(subs(S1(2),t ,t1)); z2=double(subs(S1(3),t ,t1));
% x3=double(subs(x2,u ,u1)); y3=double(subs(y2,u ,u1)); z3=double(subs(z2,u ,u1));

%x2=subs(x1,[t, u], [t1, u1])         
% %subs(x, t)

plot3(x2,y2,z2)
axis equal
xlabel('x(t)')
ylabel('y(t)')
zlabel('z(t)')
```

[Helix On Helix Cylindrical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSMe1.png)

Code for Single Helix on Toroid:

```
%   HELIX ON TORUS DIRECT FORUMLA
%
t = 0:pi/500:40*pi;
%       VARIABLES
R=3;% MAJOR RADIUS
r=1;% MINOR RADIUS
n=6;% No. of loops

xt = (R + r*cos(n*t)).*cos(t);
yt = r*sin(n*t);
zt = (R + r*cos(n*t)).*sin(t);

plot3(xt,yt,zt)
axis equal
xlabel('x(t)')
ylabel('y(t)')
zlabel('z(t)')
```

[Single_helix_torus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVAx2.png)

**Double Helix On torus**

```
%
%HELIX ON HELIX_CYLINDRICAL
clear
clc
%
syms t r R h
assume(t,'real')
assume(R,'real')
assume(h,'real')
% CYLINDRICAL HELIX
% x=h*t;
% y=R*cos(t);
% z=R*sin(t);

% % HELIX ON TORUS
% %       VARIABLES
R=3;% MAJOR RADIUS
r=1;% MINOR RADIUS
n=6;% No. of loops
x = (R + r*cos(n*t)).*cos(t);
y = r*sin(n*t);
z = (R + r*cos(n*t)).*sin(t);

% r_vec is the equation of the curve of interest: here helix
r_vec=[x;y;z];
dx=diff(x);
dy=diff(y);
dz=diff(z);
tan_vec=[dx;dy;dz];
nor_vec=diff(tan_vec)/simplify(norm(diff(tan_vec)));
binor_vec=simplify((cross( tan_vec, nor_vec))/norm(tan_vec));
%parametrized for the next curve
syms a
assume(a,'real')
%Number of turns of the second helix
n2=12;
u=n2*t;
S= r_vec + a.*nor_vec.*cos(u)+a.*binor_vec.*sin(u);
% VARIABLES FOR THE SECOND LEVEL HELIX
% a= radius 
h_num=1; R_num=3; a_num=0.5;
S1=subs(S, [h, R, a], [h_num, R_num, a_num]);
% %%Plotting
% R=6; r=2; n=5;
t1 = 0:pi/100:40*pi;
% u1 = 0:pi/15:2*pi;
% x1=R.*cos(t)+r.*cos(t).*cos(n.*t);
% y1=R*sin(t)+r*cos(n.*t).*sin(t);
% z1=r*sin(n.*t);
% x1=S1(1)
% y1=S1(2)
% z1=S1(3)
x2=double(subs(S1(1),t ,t1)); y2=double(subs(S1(2),t ,t1)); z2=double(subs(S1(3),t ,t1));
% x3=double(subs(x2,u ,u1)); y3=double(subs(y2,u ,u1)); z3=double(subs(z2,u ,u1));

%x2=subs(x1,[t, u], [t1, u1])         
% %subs(x, t)

plot3(x2,y2,z2)
axis equal
xlabel('x(t)')
ylabel('y(t)')
zlabel('z(t)')


%%
%   HELIX ON TORUS DIRECT FORUMLA
%
t = 0:pi/500:40*pi;
%       VARIABLES
R=3;% MAJOR RADIUS
r=1;% MINOR RADIUS
n=6;% No. of loops

xt = (R + r*cos(n*t)).*cos(t);
yt = r*sin(n*t);
zt = (R + r*cos(n*t)).*sin(t);

plot3(xt,yt,zt)
axis equal
xlabel('x(t)')
ylabel('y(t)')
zlabel('z(t)')
```

[Double_helix_torus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crt99.png)

Comment: You want us to confirm this  equation ?

Comment: No, I would like to have some suggestion on parametric form for the next level, Helix on helix around a torus.Thanks

Comment: You need to show your efforts. Can you 3D plot lines on a torus ? For a start, a suggestion. Try out a  straight smaller helix on a cylinder which can then be mounted(parameterized) on  another helix of a bigger straight cylinder without any eccentric toroidal secondary rotation.

Comment: @Narasimham: Thank you for encouraging me and your advise.

Comment: The tag ([tag:algebraic-geometry]) is intended for questions in a branch of mathematics called algebraic geometry (see the [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/algebraic-geometry/info).) The tags ([tag:algebra-precalculus]) and/or ([tag:geometry]) should be used for basic problems that involve both algebra and geometry. Please don't reapply the algebraic-geometry tag to this question again.