# Computing tangent and normal for a toroidal helix

Tags: parametric

I want to align objects on a toroidal helix using the normal and tangent at any point. I have it rendering using the following parametric equations from this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324527/do-these-equations-create-a-helix-wrapped-into-a-torus):

$$x = (R + r\cos{nt})\cos{t}$$
$$y = (R + r\cos{nt})\sin{t}$$
$$z = r\sin{nt}$$

Here's how it looks (with an added circle):

[image]

My understanding is that I can compute the tangent as:

$$T= \frac{d\textbf{r}}{dt}$$

$$T_x = -(R + r\cos{(nt)})\sin{t} - r n \sin{(nt)}\cos{t} $$
$$T_y = (R + r\cos{(nt)})\cos{t} - r n \sin{(nt)}\sin{t} $$
$$T_z = rn\cos{(nt)}$$

I am hoping to the compute the normal as:

$$N = \frac{d\hat{T}}{dt}$$

where $\hat{T} = \frac{\vec{T}}{\mid{T}\mid}$.

I am wondering if I am on the right track, and whether it would be possible to derive simpler expressions for $T$ and $N$. I'd appreciate any suggestions to compute the normal and tangent. Thanks!

**Update (14 Jun 2023)**

I ended up using the symmetric derivative of $T$ (normalized) - numerical approximation - to compute $N$.

$$N = \frac{T(t+\delta t) - T(t+\delta t)}{2\delta t}$$

The output from my WebGPU program is shown below. $T$, $N$, and $T\times N$ are used to align the cubes on the helix.

[image: Cubes aligned on a toroidal helix]

Comment: So many errors. The unit tangent is not given by $dr/dt$. You have to normalize. Next, $dT/dt=\kappa N |dr/dt|$.

Comment: I did not say above that the unit tangent is dr/dt.

Comment: I said that T = dr/dt. Is that incorrect? I do normalize it afterwards to compute N numerically.

Comment: $T$ stands for the unit tangent. The differential geometry formulas are based on parametrizations with speed $1$.